# Timeout execution at config file for disallowed protocols

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, webrtc

I am working on a legacy code of WebRTC Gateway. I have updated a config file for disabling unsecure protocols like SSLv3, TLS1.1 and TLS1.0 which you can see from the code snippet below;

```
# Allowed cipher list.
cipher-list="TLSv1.2+HIGH:!TLSv1.1:!TLSv1:!SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!RC4:!PSK:!3DES:!DH:!EXPORT:!LOW:!SSLv2:@STRENGTH"

# Do not allow an SSL/TLS version of protocol
#
no-sslv2
no-sslv3
no-tlsv1
no-tlsv1_1
#no-tlsv1_2
```

Then I try to test protocols with this command;

```
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect www.example.com:443
```

When I execute the command with allowed protocols, there is no failure and handshake happens. But when I change the protocol with disallowed protocols like as TLS1.1 or TLS1.0, the system does not allow the handshake but waits until timeout and then throws an exception.

If I modify the config file's protocol list as below (comment out all the protocols), the handshake failure is thrown immediately;

```
# Allowed cipher list.
cipher-list="TLSv1.2+HIGH:!TLSv1.1:!TLSv1:!SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!RC4:!PSK:!3DES:!DH:!EXPORT:!LOW:!SSLv2:@STRENGTH"

# Do not allow an SSL/TLS version of protocol
#
#no-sslv2
#no-sslv3
#no-tlsv1
#no-tlsv1_1
#no-tlsv1_2
```

I will update the product description, so I am trying to figure out this execution in deep. Does anyone have any idea why this system behavior is so?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually a protocol list of TLS 1.0. 1.1 and 1.2, and cipher string of *`HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4`* is sufficient to sidestep most SSL/TLS problems or complaints in practice. TLS 1.2 and GCM mode is icing on the cake, but it is not strictly necessary. TLS 1.2 and GCM is an authenticated encryption mode, and it is used because of past padding oracle attacks. Most (all?) implementations have removed the padding oracles, so its not much of a concern nowadays.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @jww , I am newbie at Stackoverflow, so you are right to ask this question at another related website that you mentioned above. Is there any way to transport my question to one of these websites?

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. Everyone does it at some point. You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)